# Changing variables of stored procedure in sql and combining tables SMALL DATA

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design

so i have a procedure that takes in the team ID and gives me a big table of data and i run it like this:

```
 EXEC [dbo].[playerdata_get]  @ID = 145
```

[image: teamdata]

The problem is it only gives me the data for that company and i have 3 team ids , is there any way to run this procedure for every ID with out hard coding 145,2788,39981 and add them together to look like this?

[image]

Comment: You hard-coded ID 145, what's wrong with hard-coding the others? Or do you just want to be able to execute the query without any ID and get all results? Or are those 3 IDs related in some way? If so, how?

Comment: You need to add a lot more details. What is the table(s) structure? What happens inside playerdata_get?

Comment: i just was wondering if INSTEAD of hardcoding the numbers there is a way to loop through the IDs of all teams and put them i the procedure over and over

Comment: @bigdowg in your stored procedure you can check for an existence of an ID passed in and if there is none you can do a `select` on the table that has all of the IDs and then use that for the rest of your team query. you don't even need a loop, just add it as a `join` clause or put it in your `where` clause

Comment: how would u go about that? that sounds like what i was trying to do in the code!

Comment: @bigdowg show us what you tried with the stored procedure and we can help you adjust. it'll be much easier that way

Comment: The phrase "for every ID" could mean a lot of things.  Are there only these 3 IDs in the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like.....

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultSet (Player VARCHAR(100) , ID INT , AGE INT,
                         [Weight] INT , Size INT)
GO

INSERT INTO #ResultSet 
EXEC [dbo].[playerdata_get]  @ID = 145
INSERT INTO #ResultSet 
EXEC [dbo].[playerdata_get]  @ID = 2788
INSERT INTO #ResultSet 
EXEC [dbo].[playerdata_get]  @ID = 39981
GO

SELECT * FROM #ResultSet
GO
```

Comment: ur hard coding the numbers, im looking for a way to go through every id

Comment: well then you need to show the stored procedure definition and I can recommend some changes in the stored procedure to show all values.